# Source for Ethereum transaction volume by type

Tags: transactions

I'm looking for a reliable source on the (relative) transaction volume by transaction type (e.g. exchange deposits/withdrawals, ERC-20 token transfers etc.). I found [this](https://www.bloomberg.com/toaster/v2/charts/4fd1b3fc1e844a48aae5115c6d0548ef.html?brand=markets&webTheme=markets&web=true&hideTitles=false) somewhat related chart on Bloomberg, but it doesn't state a date and I'm sure there's a more detailed view.

Does anyone know a better source?

[image]